# How to do this in Git:

Tags: git, github

I was working on one Branch say Branch1, I made changes locally and then I committed the changes but when I tried to push the changes it failed because that branch is now protected(it wasn't when I started working on it), so now I want to move/commit all these changes to a new branch and raise a PR.

I have created one branch Branch2 from Branch1, and I did the checkout to branch2.

But I don't see a single change that I made/committed in Branch1.

Is there any way i can commit all the changes to the branch2, except redoing all the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create a new branch.
From `Branch1`, you can specify which branch to push to when using git push:

```
git push remote Branch1:remotebranch
```

Comment: Getting an error  ! [remote rejected] Branch1 ->Branch1 (protected branch hook declined)

Comment: That's because you are pushing to the same branch. In my example `remotebranch` is the name of the other branch, e.g. `Branch2`

Comment: No, i am pushing to Branch 2 only, here is the command : git push origin  Branch1 : Branch2

Comment: Remove the space before and after `:`

Comment: Thank you :) . It is done but if I checkout to Branch2 now and will do Git Status, it won't show the changes because I have committed the changes in Branch1 and there is nothing in the stage? Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Regarding your second question: when you do git status, git will show you the state of the working directory. The second branch was created from the first branch where the change was already made. You can do `git show HEAD` to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Say you've already done:

```sh
git checkout develop
git checkout -b branch1
ed README.txt
git commit -am 'edit README'
git push
```

and the last "push" fails.  You can create the new branch `branch2` with the same content and history as `branch1`:

```sh
git checkout branch1     # already here from the previous block
git checkout -b branch2  # create the new branch
git log develop..branch2 # shows the commit from above
git push
```

It's helpful to clean up the stale branch too; depending on whether you want `branch1` to exist or not, either of these will work:

```sh
# Delete the unmerged branch1 with the wrong content
git branch -D branch1
```

```sh
# Reset branch1 to match the upstream
git checkout branch1
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/branch1
```